# How to expand/collapse panel inside of accordion?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm working with an accordion and I added two buttons to **expandAll/collapseAll** panels. Basically I want the user to be able to manage each panel within the accordion.

My issue is the following:

1) Let's say user expands all panels

2) Now, **collapse** ONLY first panel

3) Now, **expand** ONLY first panel

4) You have have noticed the othe other panels were collapsed (well this is my issue).

I dont want to other panels to collapse when expanding/collapsing a single panel. I want each panel to act independently. Does anyone know how to make this happen? Here's my code:

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PWdvTVB35HGlkTHYPgp0?p=preview)

```
expandAllPanels(){
this.arePanelsAllExpanded = true;
}

collapseAllPanels(){
this.arePanelsAllExpanded = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see you are using primeNG, there is option in accrodion, so you must add this

```
<p-accordion  [multiple]="true">
```

and all will work as you want. Tried on your Plunker.